# Decode with aggregate and non-aggregate results

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm trying to decode a value in a query. Based on the status, I want to either return `sysdate` or the MAX of a column:

```
SELECT DECODE(t2.productstatus, 'Stores', SYSDATE, MAX(t1.actual_moveout))
  INTO v_last_moveout
  FROM rw_product_flow t1
  JOIN rw_product_master t2
    ON t1.facility = t2.facility
   AND t1.product = t2.product
 WHERE t1.facility = p_facility
   AND t1.product = p_product;
```

However, this is throwing a ORA-00937 not a single-group group funciton error, because sysdate is not an aggregate function.  What is the best way to achieve this without writing a verbose IF block?

Comment: Doesn't that need a `group by t2.productstatus`?

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Adding `GROUP BY t1.facility, t1.product, t2.productstatus` gives the desired result.

Comment: @Laurence - Looks like we have a winner; please add that as the answer, perhaps with some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Max` on it's own without a `group by`, but once you want other information as well, you need to group the data. (MySQL differs here, in providing sensible defaults for non-grouped columns in many cases)

My psychic debugging abilities tell me that

```
GROUP BY t1.facility, t1.product, t2.productstatus
```

will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DECODE(t2.productstatus, 'Stores', SYSDATE, MAX(t1.actual_moveout) over ())
  INTO v_last_moveout
  FROM rw_product_flow t1
  JOIN rw_product_master t2
    ON t1.facility = t2.facility
   AND t1.product = t2.product
 WHERE t1.facility = p_facility
   AND t1.product = p_product;
```

I'm not 100% sure you can nest a windowing (aka analytical) function in a decode. If that gives you an error this can be easily worked around using a derived table:

```
select DECODE(productstatus, 'Stores', SYSDATE, max_moveout)
from (
    SELECT t2.productstatus, 
           MAX(t1.actual_moveout) over () as max_moveout
      INTO v_last_moveout
      FROM rw_product_flow t1
      JOIN rw_product_master t2
        ON t1.facility = t2.facility
       AND t1.product = t2.product
     WHERE t1.facility = p_facility
       AND t1.product = p_product
)
```